# ng-click : pass data selectedItem between pages angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I was able to select Items of my list, but the aim is to pass the data of the selected list in another /route when I click on it. I would need a bit of help because I don't really know how to proceed please. If you know punker examples do not hesitate to tell me :)

**Bellow is my optionSuggestionController**

```
app.controller('optionSuggestionController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('suggestions.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.suggestions = res.data;                
        });

    $scope.setMaster = function(suggestion) {
        $scope.selected = suggestion;
    }

    $scope.isSelected = function(suggestion) {
        return $scope.selected === suggestion;
    }
}])
```

**Bellow is my list of data**

```
<ul class="list-holder">
    <li ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions" ng-class="{active : isSelected(suggestion)}">
        <a ng-click="setMaster(suggestion)">{{suggestion.fromto}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Bellow is my suggestions.json**

```
[{ "fromto": "Dublin to London", "img": "http://placekitten.com/100/100" },
    { "fromto": "Dublin to Paris", "img": "http://placekitten.com/100/100" },
    { "fromto": "Dublin to Mexico", "img": "http://placekitten.com/100/100" }]
```

Comment: We'll need to know what the `sugestion` object looks like, but I'm thinking if you use a state-service to you can share the same service between two controllers and then access th clicked sugestion via the stateService :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Service or Factory to share your data between controllers, I create a Factory with your codes and call it on a control to use.

```
    app.controller('optionSuggestionController', function ($scope, $filter, $timeout, $timeout, $http, testFactory) {

            testFactory.get(function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                $scope.suggestions = resp;
            });
    });


    app.factory('testFactory', function ($http) {
        var databaseFactory = {};
        databaseFactory.get = function (callback) {

            return $http.get('suggestions.json').then(function (response) {
                databaseFactory.returnedData = response.data;
                callback(databaseFactory.returnedData);
            });
        }
        return databaseFactory;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Amir, exactly what I needed, I am going to work on that

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the provider '$rootScope'.

```
$rootScope.selected = suggestion;
```

You can access this data in an other controller.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

- You can use the provider '$rootScope'.

  > $rootScope.selected = suggestion;
- Or get param via url by provider '$route'.

  > var suggestion = $route.current.params.suggestion;